# Are strings mutable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, immutability, mutable

Are Strings mutable in Ruby? According to the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001125) doing

```
str = "hello"
str = str + " world"
```

creates a new string object with the value `"hello world"` but when we do

```
str = "hello"
str << " world"
```

It does not mention that it creates a new object, so does it mutate the `str` object, which will now have the value `"hello world"`?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, `<<` mutates the same object, and `+` creates a new one. Demonstration:

```
irb(main):011:0> str = "hello"
=> "hello"
irb(main):012:0> str.object_id
=> 22269036
irb(main):013:0> str << " world"
=> "hello world"
irb(main):014:0> str.object_id
=> 22269036
irb(main):015:0> str = str + " world"
=> "hello world world"
irb(main):016:0> str.object_id
=> 21462360
irb(main):017:0>
```

Comment: +1 for demonstrating how to determine if objects are indeed same or different

Answer (score 8):

Just to complement, one implication of this mutability is seem below:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :001 > str = "foo"
 => "foo" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :002 > ref = str
 => "foo" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :003 > str = str + "bar"
 => "foobar" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :004 > str
 => "foobar" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :005 > ref
 => "foo"
```

and

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :001 > str = "foo"
 => "foo" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :002 > ref = str
 => "foo" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :003 > str << "bar"
 => "foobar" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :004 > str
 => "foobar" 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :005 > ref
 => "foobar"
```

So, you should choose wisely the methods you use with strings in order to avoid unexpected behavior.

Also, if you want something immutable and unique throughout your application you should go with symbols:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :001 > "foo" == "foo"
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :002 > "foo".object_id == "foo".object_id
 => false 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :003 > :foo == :foo
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :004 > :foo.object_id == :foo.object_id
 => true
```

Answer (score 1):

While above answers are perfect, Just adding this answer for future readers.

> In most languages, string literals are also immutable, just like
> numbers and symbols. In Ruby versions that are less than 3, all
> strings are mutable by default. This changed in Ruby 3. Now all string
> literals are immutable by default in Ruby 3++ versions.