# replacing lines in ruby string

Tags: ruby

i'm trying to loop through a Ruby string containing many lines using the each_line method, but I also want to change them. I'm using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
string.each_line{|line| line=change_line(line)}
```

I suppose, that Ruby is sending a copy of my line and not the line itself, but unfortunatelly there is no method each_line!. I also tried with the gsub! method, using /^.*$/ to detect each line, but it seems that it calls the change_line method only ones and replaces all lines with it. Any ideas how to do that?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try starting out with a blank string too, each_lining through the string and then pushing the results onto the blank string.

```
output = "" 
string.each_line{|line| output += change_line(line)}
```

In your original example, you are correct. Your changes are occuring but they are not being ssved anywhere. `Each` in Ruby does not alter anything by default.

Comment: Can also be written as `output = string.lines.map{|line|change_line(line)}.join`.

Comment: `str += "something"` will create a new string everytime. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686621/ruby-string-concatenation-and

Answer (score 5):

@azlisum: You are not storing the result of your concatenation.  Use:

```
output = string.lines.map{|line|change_line(line)}.join
```

Comparing four ways to process by line in a string:

```
# Inject method (proposed by @steenslang)
output = string.each_line.inject(""){|s, line| s << change_line(line)}

# Join method (proposed by @Lars Haugseth)
output = string.lines.map{|line|change_line(line)}.join

# REGEX method (proposed by @olistik)
output = string.gsub!(/^(.*)$/) {|line| change_line(line)}

# String concatenation += method (proposed by @Erik Hinton)
output = "" 
string.each_line{|line| output += change_line(line)}
```

The timing with Benchmark:

```
                   user     system      total        real
Inject Time:   7.920000   0.010000   7.930000 (  7.920128)
Join Time:     7.150000   0.010000   7.160000 (  7.155957)
REGEX Time:   11.660000   0.010000  11.670000 ( 11.661059)
+= Time:       7.080000   0.010000   7.090000 (  7.076423)
```

As @steenslag pointed out, 's += a' will generate a [new string for each concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686621/ruby-string-concatenation-and) and is therefor not usually the best choice.

So given that, and given the times, your best bet is:

```
output = string.lines.map{|line|change_line(line)}.join
```

Also, this is the cleaner looking choice IMHO.

Notes:
[Using Benchmark](http://www.skorks.com/2010/03/timing-ruby-code-it-is-easy-with-benchmark/)
[Ruby-Doc: Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-bm)

Answer (score 2):

You could use gsub! passing a block to it:

```
string.gsub!(/^(.*)$/) {|line| change_line(line)}
```

source: [String#gsub!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21)

Answer (score 1):

`String#each_line` is meant for reading lines in a string, not writing them. You can use this to get the result you want like so:

```
changed_string = ""
string.each_line{ |line| changed_string += change_line(line) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give each_line a block, you'll get an enumerator, which has the inject method.

```
str = <<HERE
smestring dsfg
line 2
HERE

res = str.each_line.inject(""){|m,line|m << line.upcase}
```